# Convert data from CSV to JSON with grouping

Tags: json, csv, jq

Example csv data (top row is column header followed by three data lines);

```
floor,room,note1,note2,note3
floor1,room1,2people
floor2,room4,6people,projector
floor6,room5,20people,projector,phone
```

I need the output in json, but grouped by floor, like this;

```
floor
    room
    note1
    note2
    note3

    room
    note1
    note2
    note3

floor
    room
    note1
    note2
    note3

    room
    note1
    note2
    note3
```

So all floor1 rooms are in their own json grouping, then floor2 rooms etc.

Please could someone point me in the right direction in terms of which tools to look at and any specific functions e.g. jq + categories.  I've done some searching already and got muddled up between lots of different posts relating to csvtojson, jq and some python scripts.  Ideally I would like to include the solution in a shell script rather than a separate program/language (I have sys admin experience but not a programmer).

Many thanks

Comment: that doesn't look like json at all

Comment: I realize that my output isn't in json format, the data was trying to show the grouping, which is the crux of the issue.  If you have some constructive input I would be very pleased to hear it, I am here to learn after all. Thanks.

Comment: as far as I know, jq cannot convert CSV to JSON, it accepts only JSON input. So look for a CSV to JSON converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this can get you started.

Use a programming language like Python to convert the CSV data into a dictionary data structure by splitting on the commas, and use the JSON library to dump your dictionary out as JSON.

I have assumed that actually you expect to have more than one room per floor and thus I took the liberty to adjust your input data a little.

```
import json

csv = """floor1,room1,note1,note2,note3
floor1,room2,2people
floor1,room3,3people
floor2,room4,6people,projector
floor2,room5,3people,projector
floor3,room6,1person
"""

response = {}

for line in csv.splitlines():
    fields = line.split(",")
    floor, room, data = fields[0], fields[1], fields[2:]
    if floor not in response:
        response[floor] = {}
    response[floor][room] = data

print json.dumps(response)
```

If you then run that script and pipe it into `jq` (where JQ is just used for pretty-printing the output on your screen ; it is not really required) you will see:

```
$ python test.py | jq . 
{
  "floor1": {
    "room2": [
      "2people"
    ],
    "room3": [
      "3people"
    ],
    "room1": [
      "note1",
      "note2",
      "note3"
    ]
  },
  "floor2": {
    "room4": [
      "6people",
      "projector"
    ],
    "room5": [
      "3people",
      "projector"
    ]
  },
  "floor3": {
    "room6": [
      "1person"
    ]
  }
}
```